# different MTU on a single link

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

What should be the correct behaviour in Linux, when the same link has different MTUs, e.g.

```
[HostA  eth0 MTU 1500] <--> [eth0 MTU 500 HostB]
```

When I do `ping -s 1460 HostB` from HostA, I don't see anything in `tcpdump` on B's side. I also don't observer any stats `ethtool -S` on the HostB.

Thanks.